# How to redirect with CORS with lambda

Tags: api, lambda, cors, amp-html

I am getting following error

```
Access to fetch at 'https://mywebsite.com/private-post.html' 
(redirected from 'https://api.mywebsite.com/login') 
from origin 'https://mywebsite.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
If an opaque response serves your needs, 
set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I have following cors preflight set to `https://api.mywebsite.com`. `https://mywebsite.com` is static website. I am not sure if it has cors.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ['https://mywebsite.com', 'https://api.mywebsite.com']
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: [*]
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: [DELETE, GET, OPTION, PUT, HEAD, PATCH, POST]
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

So first I make post request from `https://mywebsite.com/login.html` to `https://api.mywebsite.com/login` endpoint. And after successuful login I am doing following redirect with lambda. While having above cors. And I cannot redirect to any page because of error above.

```
const response = {
        statusCode: 303,
        headers: {
            'Location': 'https://mywebsite.com/private-post.html'
        }
    }

    return response
```

**Edit**

I tried setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: [*]` but then I cannot set `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`.

So to fix that I set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ['https://*']` now I can allow credentials however on redirect the cors error still remains the same.

Comment: Have u tried setting `mode: no-cors` in the header?

Comment: Try setting `Access-Control-Allow-Headers:*` as header in the response object while sending back the response.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` is not supported if I set `Access-Control-Allow-Headers:*`. I cannot login without that. I did set `mode: no-cors` still lambda automatically adds `access-control-allow-origin: https://mywebsite.com` to the header along with `mode:no-cors`.

Answer (score 0):

> `https://mywebsite.com` is static website. I am not sure if it has cors.

The error message days it doesn’t but, since you are trying to read the content with JS, it needs to.

You can’t use a redirect to grant CORS permission for a resource you don’t control. If you could, then an attacker could (for example) create a site that redirects to your online banking, and then have JS on their attacking site access your accounts through it. It would make the Same Origin Policy worthless.

Comment: I am using amp(accelerated mobile pages) login. And it requires me to redirect on success to `/login.html#success=true`. Basically same page with `#success=true` or `success=false`. Also on logout I am supposed to redirect to same url and somehow refresh the page so user name and other info will go away. They have redirected with expressjs in official documentation and working example with cors enabled. why can't I do it?

Comment: You can't do it with Ajax. Probably it intends you to use a regular form submission.

Comment: [official running example on heroku](https://rocky-sierra-1919.herokuapp.com/) and the [source code from official repo](https://github.com/ampproject/samples/tree/master/amp-paywall-demo)  You can see for yourself. Because its using different/legacy framework its possible. I wanted to replicate it inside lambda function and throw 401 status code based on origin url. But its not letting me do that.

Comment: Looking at that, the authorisation endpoint response with JSON or plain text, but not a redirect.

Comment: You are looking at wrong endpoint. `/controllers/amp-access/login.js` there is `/submit` post endpoint for login and `/logout` get endpoint for logout.

Comment: https://github.com/ampproject/samples/blob/master/amp-paywall-demo/views/amp-access/login.html — And that’s a regular form with **no Ajax** that the example app uses to access it.

Comment: I said in my question that `/login.html` has form(regular) that makes post request `/login` endpoint and after successful login I am doing the redirect. Just instead of express I am using Lambda.

Comment: You didn’t say that, and the error message says you are using `fetch`, not a regular form submission!

Comment: I am not 100% sure if its fetch but I use AMP Form for submission https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-form/?format=websites

Comment: @ApoorvMote — The documentation makes it clear that it can be configured to use fetch or a regular form submission. You must have configured it to use fetch.